# Is it possible to have drop down boxes in a tablesorter plugin?

Tags: php, ajax, tablesorter

I have a table that generates perfectly using php, ajax and the tablesorter plugin.  I now would like to make a few of the input fields into dropdown boxes so the user can select an option if it needs to be changed.  This all will then need to be saved to a database. Here is what I have so far:

```
    $('#getInfo').live('click', function() {
//clear table before search
    $("#inventoryUpdate tbody tr").remove();
    $('#messageInv').html('Please be patient, this might take a minute');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "getInventory.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: ({skuStart: $("#startSkuRange").val(), skuEnd: $("#endSkuRange").val(), processDate: $("#processDate").val(),
           source: $("#source").val()}),
    success: function(data){
        $('#messageInv').hide(); 
        //console.log(data);
                    var myselectoptions = ''; 
        if(data.isbn2 === null){
                $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td>No Records Found</td></tr>');
            }else{
        for(var x=0;x<data.isbn2.length;x++)
                {
          $.each(data.defect2[x], function(index, val)
            {
             myselectoptions += '<option value="'+data.defect2[x][index].option+'">'+data.defect2[x][index].option+'</option>';
            });
        $("#inventoryUpdate").append('<tr><td id="tableSKU">'+data.sku[x]+'</td><td id="tableISBN">'+data.isbn2[x]+
                 '</td><td><input type="text" id="tableQuantity" value="'+data.quantity[x]+
                 '"/></td><td><select id="tableDefect">'+myselectoptions+
                 '"</select></td><td><input type="text" id="tableSource" value="'+data.source[x]+
                 '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableFeature" value="'+data.feature[x]+
                 '"/></td><td><input type="text"  id="tableLocation" value="'+data.location[x]+
                '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableProcessDate" value="'+data.processDate[x]+
                '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableBookType" value="'+data.booktype[x]+
                '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableCreatedBy" value="'+data.created[x]+
                '"/></td><td><input type="text" id="tableModifiedBy" value="'+data.modified[x]+
                '"/></td></tr>');
                                    }
        $("#inventoryUpdate").trigger("update");
            } // end of else statement
    } // end of success function
});// end of ajax call
}); // end of inventory update function
```

I would like to have the tableDefect and tableFeature inputs become drop down boxes that are populated dynamically, and default to the current info from the database.  For example, if the defect from the database is "rip in dust jacket" that would be the option that is selected, but I also need the rest of the options (no defects, water damage etc.) from the database to be available if it needs to be changed.  I would think that I need to change the input type to a select, but then how do I go about populating it?  Would that require another call to the database for the information?
Is this even possible to do with this plug-in?
EDIT: I have pasted in the new code based on the answer below, I now am getting 19 "options" (it just says undefined not the actual value returned) for the first record, 38 for the second etc.  There should only be 19 options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading you correctly just replace `<input type="text"......>` with
`<select id=...><option>...</option></select>`

As far as populating the selects dynamically that can be handled a few different ways. With your ajax you would get the select values maybe by changing your existing

`data.defect[x]` into a multidimensional object so instead of it being just a string you would  output an array that will get converted to JSON on your backend so your object would look like

`defect[{"option":"value"},{"option":"value"},{"option":"value"},{"option":"value"}]`

Where when your building your table in the succession part you would loop over that object. You would essentially do the same as you do now.. except. your select would look like

```
var myselectoptions = '';
   $.each(data.defect[x], function(index, val)
          {
             myselectoptions += '<option value="'+data.source[x][index].option+'">'+data.source[x][index].option+'</option>';
          });
'"/></td><td><select id="tableDefect">'+myselectoptions+'....
```

now this is pure concept, I haven't tested it, and its likely to need some tweaking to fit your needs specifically but this is the core concept of one of a few ways you can handle what you want done, that fits into what you are currently doing, without having to alter it too much.

Comment: what would the source be?  in my ajax back end I used defect2 and defect_id for my array's, does source then become these? Also, what is the index and do I need to increment it ([index][x])?

Comment: x is based off your existing for loop.. index is similar in what it is, but will apply to the each loops iterations and not the for loops iterations so if you have 10 options to be listed index will be 0-9 for that set of defect objects. As for your backend. However you define defect now as a string would be similar to the javascript but building it as a string for output for the javascript or object rather.

Comment: With a little tweaking I was able to get it to work, mostly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I now am having trouble with setting the selected variable, any thoughts? the new code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990972/use-select-tags-with-table-sorter-plug-in-and-have-it-default-to-a-given-value